# Как отправить определённый IP-Адрес на приложение Android

Tags: android, ip

Есть приложение на телефоне, которое определяет твоё местоположение на карте (ну там со своими фишками, это неважно), чем-то схоже с **Google Maps**. Как отправлять определённый **IP-Адрес** на это приложение? *VPN не подходит*

Comment: Что такое отправлять IP-адрес? И при чём тут местоположение?

Comment: Как и другие данные с сервера

Comment: Три буквы: VPN.

Comment: @andreymal чтобы приложение думало что я, находясь на одном месте, передвигался в определённом направлении, например каждую секунду двигаясь на 1 метр

Comment: @AlexeyTen неа, в VPN ты можешь иметь только тот айпи, которые предоставляет сервер, а как мне надо я описал в комментарии выше

Comment: @ВладимирПечерский к IP-адресам это не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: @andreymal можете, пожалуйста, объяснить как это сделать? :3

Comment: Так может вам не ip, а gps нужен?

Comment: @AlexeyTen честно, вообще не представляю как сделать то что я описал в вопросе, поэтому и обратился за помощью :)

Comment: Гуглите fake gps

Comment: @AlexeyTen, да, помогло, спасибо, но не могли вы объяснить принцип работы приложений такого типа?) Если не трудно, с примерами кода